# Review favorite tags - counterintuitive behaviour

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-bydesign, review, tag-watching

In the "review" section there is a list of tags on the right side. If you click it, the reviewable questions/answers get filtered.

Right underneath is the list of favorite tags, but if you click it you go back to the main questions section. Is this intended? I find it very counterintuitive and would expect it to behave the same as the tag links above.

Answer (score 3):

That is a little weird, but it's actually kind of correct in an overall consistency way. When you're on a question list page, the favorite tags are under the related tags list, and they don't have the same behavior, either (related tags adds the tag to your search; favorite goes to that tag alone).

The rule is that, no matter where you are on the site, the favorite and ignored tags lists work the same way. I completely agree that it's confusing at first, but if you look at it from the network level, it kinda makes sense.

Comment: Well, the other example you mentioned honestly bugs me out as well. And even though I clicked the links there many times already, I still can't get used to its behaviour. I understand the point of consistency, but if it confuses users it still is a problem. Maybe move the list somewhere else then?